# Unsupported operand(s) types(s) when trying to assertAlmostEqual/assertEqual

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am trying to test that two objects are equal. The type of this objects is Point which is a class defined by ROS (Robot Operating System). I have the following test:

```
def test_when_getting_position_after_2s_then_position_at_2s_is_returned(self):
    self.expected_position.x = -self.radius
    self.expected_position.y = 0
    self.assertAlmostEqual(
        self.expected_position,
        self.trajectory.get_position_at(2))
```

I am using `unittest`, and when I try to assert if they are almost equal, I am getting an error which says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Point' and 'Point'

I get the same error when I use `assertEqual`, and I know I can do this:

```
self.assertAlmostEqual(self.expected_position.x, self.trajectory.get_position_at(1).x)
self.assertAlmostEqual(self.expected_position.y, self.trajectory.get_position_at(1).y)
```

However, I would like to be able to assert position and not specific fields. How can I achieve this?

**Edit: The full traceback of the exception is:**

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/m/turtlebot_ws/src/trajectory_tracking/src/test/trajectory/test_astroid_trajectory.py", line 26, in test_when_getting_position_after_1s_then_position_at_1s_is_returned
    self.assertAlmostEqual(self.expected_position, self.trajectory.get_position_at(1))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 554, in assertAlmostEqual
    if round(abs(second-first), places) == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Point' and 'Point'
```

Comment: What is the *full traceback* of the exception?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I have just edited my question providing the full traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assertAlmostEqual(a, b)` requires `abs(a - b)` to be valid, but you did not define the subtraction operator for the Point type, thus the error.

```
class Point(object):
    ...
    def __sub__(self, other):   # <-- define the subtraction operator so `a - b` is valid
        return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

class Vector(object):
    ...
    def __abs__(self):    # <-- define the absolute function so `abs(v)` is valid
        return (self.x*self.x + self.y*self.y)**0.5
```

---

If you cannot provide `__sub__` in the class definition, you could use monkey-patching to provide it in your test case.

```
def sub_point(self, other):
    return complex(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
    # ^ for simplicity we abuse a complex number as a 2D vector.

Point.__sub__ = sub_point
```

Comment: Nice!! Typo on the `return` of the absolute value function.

Comment: @kennytm, what if this classes are provided by a framework? How can I do this, should I use inheritance and implement this method on them, or is there any way to make an extension of a class?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf: You could use monkey-patching. `Point.__sub__ = function`.

Comment: @kennytm, I didn't know about monkey-patching, but I just have checked, and this is an amazing solution. Thank you so much. I possible, could please update your answer indicating about this feature monkey-patching.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129560/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-kennytm).